# Infinite Fibonacci Sequence with Memoized in Java 8

Tags: java, javascript, lambda, java-8, java-stream

Firstly, I'm a JavaScript programmer, and fairly new to Java8 and trying the new functional feature.

Since I expertise JS coding, I implemented my own JS lazy-functional library for proof of concept.

https://github.com/kenokabe/spacetime

Using the library, I could write **Infinite sequence of Natural numbers and Fibonacci** as below:

**JavaScript**

```
var spacetime = require('./spacetime');
var _ = spacetime.lazy(); 

var natural = _(function(n)   //memoized automatically
{
  return n;    // Natural numbers is defined as the `n`th number becomes `n`
});

var natural10 = _(natural)
  .take(10)
  .compute(function(x)
  {
    console.log(x);
  });


//wrap a recursive function to memoize
// must be at the definition in the same scope
var fib = _(function(n)
{
  if (n <= 1)
    return 1; // as the Fib definition in Math
  else
    return fib(n - 2) + fib(n - 1); // as the Fib definition in Math
});

var fib10 = _(fib)
  .take(10)
  .compute(function(x)
  {
    console.log(x);
  });
```

Clear enough. The point is that I can define Natural/Fibonacci infinite sequence as the math definition as it is, then later compute the required part of the infinite sequence with lazy-evaluation.

So, now I wonder if I can do the same manner with Java8.

For natural sequence, I had post another Question here.

[Infinite sequence of Natural numbers with Java8 generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26277330/infinite-sequence-of-natural-numbers-with-java8-generator)

One of the way to define Natural sequence is to use `iterator` of Java8:

**Java8**

```
IntStream natural = IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i + 1);

natural
 .limit(10)
 .forEach(System.out::println);
```

I observe `IntStream natural = IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i + 1);` is a fair definition of natural numbers in math sense.

However, I wonder if it's possible to define it as I did before, that is,

**JavaScript**

```
var natural = _(function(n)   //memoized automatically
    {
      return n;    // Natural numbers is defined as the `n`th number becomes `n`
    });
```

because this looks more concise. Unfortunately, the answers suggest it's probably not possible even we use `generate`.

In addition, `IntStream.iterate` does not fit for Fibonacci sequence.

I seek web to `generate` indefinite sequence of  Fibonacci, the best results I found are

http://blog.informatech.cr/2013/05/08/memoized-fibonacci-numbers-with-java-8/

**Java8**

```
private static Map<Integer,Long> memo = new HashMap<>();
static {
   memo.put(0,0L); //fibonacci(0)
   memo.put(1,1L); //fibonacci(1)
}

//And for the inductive step all we have to do is redefine our Fibonacci function as follows:

public static long fibonacci(int x) {
   return memo.computeIfAbsent(x, n -> fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2));
}
```

This is not an infinite sequence (lazy `Stream` in Java8).

and

[Providing Limit condition on Stream generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21650155/providing-limit-condition-on-stream-generation)

**Java8**

```
Stream.generate(new Supplier<Long>() {
    private long n1 = 1;
    private long n2 = 2;

    @Override
    public Long get() {
        long fibonacci = n1;
        long n3 = n2 + n1;
        n1 = n2;
        n2 = n3;
        return fibonacci;
    }
}).limit(50).forEach(System.out::println);
```

This is an infinite sequence (lazy `Stream` in Java8), and you could say it's defined as Math.
However I do not like this implementation because, as you can see, there are many internal valuable to obtain the sequence such as `n1` `n2` `n3` then `fibonacci`, accordingly the code structure is complicated and **you need to control mutable state which is anti-functional** manner - unlike the math definition, and probably this is not memoized.

So, here's my question. With Java8 `Stream`, is there any way to write a code to define the infinite sequence of fibonacci in concise math manner with memoization like

**JavaScript**

```
 var fib = _(function(n)
    {
      if (n <= 1)
        return 1; // as the Fib definition in Math
      else
        return fib(n - 2) + fib(n - 1); // as the Fib definition in Math
    });
```

Thanks for your thought.

Comment: This other article [Java Infinite Streams](http://www.ticocoding.com/java-infinite-streams/) provides a conceptual explanation of streams and the last example demonstrates an infinite stream of fibonacci numbers, although it does not use Java 8 streams.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can take your map-based memoized fibonacci(x) and make an infinite stream out of it like this:

```
LongStream fibs = IntStream.iterate(1, i->i+1).mapToLong(i -> fibonacci(i));
```

But the easiest way to make an infinite stream of fibonacci numbers is like this:

```
LongStream fibs = Stream.iterate(
        new long[]{1, 1},
        f -> new long[]{f[1], f[0] + f[1]}
).mapToLong(f -> f[0]);
```

As the article you linked to points out, "infinite" really means "until long overflows" which happens quickly.  If you want to generate hundreds of fibonacci numbers, replace long with BigInteger:

```
    Stream<BigInteger> bigFibs = Stream.iterate(
            new BigInteger[]{BigInteger.ONE, BigInteger.ONE},
            f -> new BigInteger[]{f[1], f[0].add(f[1])}
    ).map(f -> f[0]);
```

Comment: Great.Although the style presentation of the function in Java8 still confuses me, I could fairly confirm it corresponds the math definition. Perhaps I would post another question. What is `map` or `mapToLong` (f -> f[0]), I know what the `map` is, but I could not follow the logical role here. Also the `map` has automatic memorisation functionality?

Comment: I post another Q for this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26290716/map-based-memoized-in-java8

Comment: You may want to study [this related question and its answers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25880331/2711488)…

Comment: please explain flow of this answer and parameter given LongStream fibs = Stream.iterate(
        new long[]{1, 1},
        f -> new long[]{f[1], f[0] + f[1]}
).mapToLong(f -> f[0]);