# `map-based memoized` in Java8?

Tags: java, dictionary, functional-programming, java-8, java-stream

In my previous Question here

[Infinite Fibonacci Sequence with Memoized in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26288818/infinite-fibonacci-sequence-with-memoized-in-java-8/26289686#26289686)

I asked how to write a code to define the infinite sequence of fibonacci in concise math manner with memoization with Java8 Stream.

Thankfully, I've got an answer, and the code below seems to work well:

```
    LongStream fibs = Stream
            .iterate(
            new long[]{1, 1},
            f -> new long[]{f[1], f[0] + f[1]}
            )
            .mapToLong(f -> f[0]);

    fibs
            .limit(30)
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
55
89
144
233
377
610
987
1597
2584
4181
6765
10946
17711
28657
46368
75025
121393
196418
317811
514229
832040

Although the code style presentation of the function in Java8 still confuses me, I could fairly confirm it corresponds the math definition of fibonacci sequence.

The computing speed suggests it memoizes the function, and he says

> You can take your map-based memoized fibonacci(x) and make an infinite stream out of it like this:

What is the `map-based memoized` in Java8?

Also, I could not follow the logical role of

`.mapToLong(f -> f[0]);`

Can you explain. Any reference/documentation is also appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the comment you quoted.  It was referring to `IntStream.iterate(1,i->i+1).mapToLong(i->fibonacci(i));`  In the original question, you had a definition of memoized fibonacci function but said "This is not an infinite sequence".  So I was showing how to use that already memoized function to make an infinite stream.

Answer (score 0):

As Misha said, it's the `Supplier<Long>` [functional interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#approach6) that's memoised because it stores two private variables `n1` and `n2`. The object has then a ***mutable*** state and has side effects. It could cause problems when using paralellization.

```
new Supplier<Long>() {
    private long n1 = 1;
    private long n2 = 2;

    @Override
    public Long get() {
        long fibonacci = n1;
        long n3 = n2 + n1;
        n1 = n2;
        n2 = n3;
        return fibonacci;
    }
}
```

At opposite the solution with the `iterate` is immutable and is ready for parallelization. It generates a stream of `long` arrays of size 2, starting from [1,1] and iteratively applying the function `f -> new long[]{f[1], f[0] + f[1]}`

```
.iterate(
        new long[]{1, 1},
        f -> new long[]{f[1], f[0] + f[1]}
        )
```